# delete files from usb (mac os journle)

Tags: macos, linux-mint, journaling

I have a flash drive which is formated as mac osx extended journel. It has some data I want to remove some files from the flash drive, I dont have access to Mac OS how can I delete files from my flash drive?

I am using Linux-mint 13 as my OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try mounting the drive in linux, it should be able to deal with it. In fact it should just mount automatically. If not, try this:

mkdir test

```
sudo mount -f hfsplus /dev/sdb1 test
```

Replace /dev/sdb1 with whatever letter your usb drive has been assigned to. If you don't know it, jusr run dmesg |tail  after plugging the drive in and look for something like:

```
[22361.446665] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[22361.447759]  sdb: sdb1
[22361.450207] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
```

For more information see [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-mount-hfsplus-usb-drive-rw-in-ubuntu-924839/) and [here](http://raamdev.com/2008/mounting-hfs-with-write-access-in-debian/).